# gpg symmetric encryption decrypts without asking for the symmetric key when --decrypt option is used

Tags: symmetric, pgp

```
If you encrypt with:

gpg -o gpg.symmetric.test.gpg --symmetric gpg.symmetric.test

and then decrypt with:

gpg -o gpg.symmetric.test1 --decrypt gpg.symmetric.test.gpg  # --decrypt option mistakenly included

the output gives:

gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase

and decrypts the file WITHOUT ASKING FOR THE KEY!  This would allow anybody
to decrypt any symmetrically encrypted file.  The --decrypt option is not
needed or supposed to be used, but the result is a disaster.

I tested with a small ascii text file and did a diff on the original and the
decrypted file.  They are identical.  I ran 'file' on the encrypted file:

file gpg.symmetric.test.gpg
gpg.symmetric.test.gpg: GPG symmetrically encrypted data (AES256 cipher)

I redid the test without the --decrypt option and the symmetric key was
queried for.
```

Comment: IIRC GPG uses the default key on your machine as the encryption/decryption key, and the passphrase is to allow for decryption to work with other machines. Essentially it secretly creates and stores the actual encryption key, and then encrypts that with the passphrase and combines the encrypted key and the encrypted plaintext into the output.

Comment: On that note, I strongly recommend [age](https://age-encryption.org) over GPG for encryption, it's much easier to use.

Comment: **The agent remembers it.** Crossdupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103034/gnupg-decryption-not-asking-for-passphrase https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395875/gpg-does-not-ask-for-password https://superuser.com/questions/1346376/gpg-decrypt-not-asking-for-password-and-just-decrypting-why https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093848/gpg-decrypts-files-without-asking-for-password